# Error in SQL Syntax - ' '', '', now())'

Tags: php, mysql, string, int

I am trying to insert a row into database and im getting the following error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '', now())' at line 1.
```

And if I use single quote outside `$gradeid` it will get converted to string and since my database column is integer and it is also a foreign key, even this gets failed with the following error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`mytable1`, CONSTRAINT `activitygoalmaster_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`intGradeID`) REFERENCES `mytable2` (`intGradeID`))
```

Im not getting whats the error? May be some simple mistake but Im not getting it. Please help. My code in php is

```
  $title = $_POST['Title'];
  $gradeid = $_POST['GradeID'];
  $masterimgpath = $_POST['MasterImgPath'];
  $description = $_POST['Description'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO activitygoalmaster(vchTitle, intGradeID, vchMasterImgPath, vchDescription, dtCreatedAt)VALUES('$title', $gradeid, '$masterimgpath', '$description', now())";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `gradeid` is empty. Try to verify it.

Do not use `mysql-*` functions, because this is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or pdo with prepared statement.

Comment: This is correct. Even the description and image path seem to be empty but obviously they are in quotes so they don't raise an error

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens. That is correct all the fields were empty. Forgot to put method="POST" in the html form. But my head was so stick to sql error that I didnt even check that. My bad.. Sorry for being such a dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Please check table structure and his value.

print your $sql before execute it. so you can find error easily.

Comment: Thanks joni jerr.. the fields were empty.

Answer (score 0):

**I have a question:** `intGradeID` column is `int()` right? Is it a `varchar()`? If it is a `varchar()` then it really needs single quotes in the `insert` query.

To solve the error with `a foreign key constraint fails`, please insert to `mytable2` the `grade id` first before inserting it to `mytable1`. It shows this error because it is required by a `foreign key` on `mytable1`.

Comment: intGradeID column is integer and mytable2 also has the proper data.. The field $gradeid was empty so the error occurred.. Anyways thanks for the help..